# Gracefully handle uncaught exception in forked process with a socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, fork, child-process

I'm not able to find a way of how to properly handle a situation when a forked process **that has a socket sent to it** fails.

Here is example of `server.js`:

```js
'use strict';

var http = require('http');
var fork = require('child_process').fork;

var srv = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var f = fork('./client.js');
  f.send('socket', res.socket);
});

srv.listen(7331, 'localhost', function () {
  console.log('server started');

  var req = http.request({
    port: 7331,
    path: '/'
  }, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
      console.log('RESPONSE', res.statusCode, res.headers, body);
    });
  });
  req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('REQUEST ERROR', e.stack);
  });
  req.end();
});
```

and of `client.js`:

```js
throw new Error('Client error');
```

I get the following output:

```
    server started
client.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { throw new Error('Client Error');
                                                              ^

Error: Client Error
    at Object.<anonymous> (client.js:1:69)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:972:3
REQUEST ERROR Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:209:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:294:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:450:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:17)
```

Is it possible to handle an uncaught exception in a forked process in given situation and generate a friendly response with status code and the error description in body?

What I've tried:

1. subscribed to child's `close` event in `server.js` and sent response from there with no luck - `This socket is closed.` is thrown
2. did some preparation in `client.js` before throwing an error: subscribed to `uncaughtException` and sent to socket some response data - still `socket hang up` and no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to absence of activity here, I posted the question in nodejs repo https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4745, where it got attention from nodejs contributors.

To sum up: that is not possible to use socket in parent process that was sent to child because it get's destroyed as soon as `send()` is called.

So the only way to solve the problem is to do some preparation in `client.js` before error happens. I pointent out in **try #2** that I did that, but maybe I was doing it wrong... With the following `client.js` code, everything works good:

```
'use strict';

let socket;

process.on('uncaughtException', function (e) {
  socket.write(`HTTP/1.1 500 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: ${e.message.length}\n\n${e.message}`);
});

process.on('message', function (type, s) {
  socket = s;
  routine();
});


function routine() {
  throw new Error('Client error');
}
```